# Run <SCRIPT> inside Ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 to create my web application. It uses Ajax to load pages like an app would.

However, I am trying to make my Ajax-loaded page run my "ad" code and display.

If you take a look at my ad code

```
<center id="ads">
    <script type="text/javascript" data-run="init">
        atOptions = {
            'key' : '08d1ebd917b9392c0b306e455b220d4e',
            'format' : 'iframe',
            'height' : 50,
            'width' : 320,
            'params' : {}
        };
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bcloudhost.com/08d1ebd917b9392c0b306e455b220d4e/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>
</center>
```

You'll see it works when you call it on a direct page that wasn't loaded with Ajax. However when you load it with Ajax it doesn't even run.

If you take a look at the ad's source code [here](http:///www.bcloudhost.com/08d1ebd917b9392c0b306e455b220d4e/invoke.js) you'll see that it creates an iframe, etc...

I am trying to get this to load into my Ajax page which looks like this.

[Code (I had to put it externally due to Stack Overflow restrictions)](https://pastebin.com/urAjgeKX)

Comment: _However when you load it with AJAX_ you mean page or `document.write(....` ??

Comment: Did you try running it with page onload function; clarify 'data-run="init" '

Comment: I really don't know however to me it seems like ajax and they also say AJAX in their documentation https://v1.framework7.io/docs/. 

Here's their load page function

https://pastebin.com/VhF0Am3y

Comment: @Johnsackson yes I tried that I didn't work sadly

Comment: @JamesKowalski, It works perfectly fine in my local server; does it throw any error?

Comment: @Johnsackson It throughs no errors, should I record a video?

Comment: @Johnsackson https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UXwNvZMTazA_kc2VwANjZ86GJ8KYFZuZ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

That is some dodgy looking code. I would say the problem here is [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You're loading the script in from a cloud hosting service from within an iframe loaded from an Ajax request. Crossing origins all over the place.

Instead of loading the script in the `src` attribute, maybe you could put the JavaScript code directly between the `script` tags?

Comment: That breaks AdsTerra's Terms of Services, it needs to be loaded from their URL.